# What is wrong with my makefile? Cannot find implementation

Tags: c++, makefile

This is my Makefile:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -std=c++11 

default: main

main: core.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp core.o -o run.exe

core.o: core.h core.cpp display.h eventhandler.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c core.cpp

eventhandler.o: eventhandler.h eventhandler.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c eventhandler.cpp

clean:
    $(RM) run.exe *.o *~
```

But when trying to compile it I get an error saying it cannot find the implementation of a function that is defined in eventhandler.cpp, but I am sure it's there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try: ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o prog main.cpp core.cpp display.cpp eventhandler.cpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
main: core.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp core.o -o run.exe
```

Should be

```
main: core.o eventhandler.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp core.o eventhandler.o -o run.exe
```